# How to change a bool in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a to-do list in python, and ways to modify it. One of the functions is to check the task off. Here is the dictionary:

```
checked = bool

todolist = {
    0: {
        "task": "Finish this program",
        checked: False
    }
}
```

Here is the function for checking off or unchecking a task:

```
try:
    checkindex = int(input("Todo index >> "))
    todolist[checkindex].get(checked) = not todolist[checkindex].get(checked)
except ValueError or IndexError:
    print("ERROR: Not a valid index")
```

If I see check the task again, this is what I want to see:

```
todolist = {
    0: {
        "task": "Finish this program",
        checked: True
    }
}
```

However, I get an error on `todolist[checkindex].get(checked)` saying "Can't assign to function call". How do I fix this?

Comment: @mousetail Technically it's fine here since `checked` was previously aliased to `bool`, but the OP probably doesn't understand what they're doing here.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code (`type` as dictionary index for one) but the error is assigning to `.get()`, why not use `[]` instead? That supports assignment

Comment: @PatrickArtner that would still be assigning to a function call and give the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `checked = bool`, you're not declaring `checked` as a boolean, but instead aliasing the builtin `bool` function to the name `checked`. That this works is just coincidental. Instead, just use a string key:

```
todolist = {
    0: {
        "task": "Finish this program",
        "checked": False
    }
}
```

When you're toggling the task, you can just assign to the `"checked"` key:

```
try:
    checkindex = int(input("Todo index >> "))
    todolist[checkindex]["checked"] = not todolist[checkindex]["checked"]
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    print("ERROR: Not a valid index")
```

I also fixed `except ValueError or IndexError`, that wouldn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: I would like to say that your solution at the top is correct, the bottom results in a syntax error.

Comment: @Boopiester Ah, thanks, fixed it. Apparently parentheses are required.